# Homepage product order is changed if changing product list order (desc / asc)

Tags: product-list, sorting, category-products

I show product on my HomePage by using following method :

```
  {{block type="xxxx/catalog_product_list" category_id="283" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

By using a category i can choose the order of my product `(Category Products > Position)`

---

The problem is that if i sort by desc or asc a product list then the homepage product order is changed based on product ID (desc or asc)

I want my homepage product to keep the Category Products > Position order even if we sort product list by desc or asc, is it possible ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This has been coming for `_beforeToHtml` function `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`.Here magento is set product listing sorty

below code:

```
if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
    $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
}
```

If i set parameter for home page product list just like

```
if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
    $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
}
```

If i set parameter for home page product list just like

```
sort_by="position"
default_direction="desc"
```

then it may be work...

```
{{block type="xxxx/catalog_product_list" category_id="283" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"  sort_by="position" default_direction="desc" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
    $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
}
```

If i set parameter for home page product list just like

```
if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
    $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
}
```

Comment: Isn't is exactly the same Amit Bera has posted?